# How to make an anchor fill the height of its containing div

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I know this is really basic to some of you, but I don't know enough css to make this happen.

I'm trying to make my own version of a spinner, and it will hook into jqueryui themes, so has to at least initially use their classes.  I also need to make the widget able to change its height (and width) dynamically.

My issue is that I don't know how to resize the buttons to fit the height of their container.  If I actively set the height of the `.ui-spinner` div, the container is too small to fit the text.  If I don't, then the div is bigger, so the anchors need to be as well, but I don't know how big.  Looking at it with developer tools, I don't see any margins or paddings to account for the extra size.

I see [How to style an anchor tag to look like a button with the same height as the button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121823/how-to-style-an-anchor-tag-to-look-like-a-button-with-the-same-height-as-the-but) keeps popping up as a similar question, but I've already set the style to be inline-block.

Here's what I currently have.  I've made a fiddle for it at http://jsfiddle.net/37za8/

#### HTML

```html
<div class="ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-spinner">
    <a class="ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-button ui-button-text-only ui-state-default" tabindex="-1" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0; display: inline-block;">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>
</a>

    <input class="ui-spinner-input" style="margin: 0;" value="0" />

    <a class="ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-button ui-button-text-only ui-state-default" tabindex="-1" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0; display: inline-block;">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```javascript
var _selector = ".ui-spinner"

$(_selector + " .ui-spinner-input").css("height", "18px");
$(_selector + " a").css("height", "18px");

$(_selector + " .ui-spinner-input").css("width", "52px");
$(_selector + " a").css("width", "24px");
$(_selector + " span").css("margin-left", "4px");
```

I can change anything you all say will help, as long as the result is dynamically sizable.  I'm sure this will be easy for most of you.  Thanks in advance!

#### Edit

For clarification, I'm trying to eventually imitate the jqueryui spinner.  I'm attempting to make a widget/component where the height can be set before displaying.  A simple example of jqueryui handling it is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8L5zD/).  The component I built has a setHeight function which will set the height of the widget.  All it is is those two lines that set the height in jQuery.  There must be some way to set up the css (or add more jquery if necessary) so that I can dynamically change the height.

Comment: can u use a different height than 18px? i tried 24px and it looks ok - http://jsfiddle.net/37za8/1/

Comment: Yes.  It happens that when I set it to 18, the box ends up being 25 pixels, so 24-26pixels should look decent.  That relies on looking up the height in dev tools and then hardcoding, though.

Comment: so your question is what is the right code that will deduce the right number of pixels so that you dont have to hard code it? how about css? can you redefine css?

Comment: Either deduce the right number of pixels, or simply make the css do it manually.  I can change anything, other than the constraints of starting with the jqueryui classes and that the height be dynamically sizable.

Comment: Is there any reason you are setting the widths with jquery?  how's this: http://jsfiddle.net/37za8/8/

Comment: @Pete - that code uses a lot of css syntax I haven't seen before (largely the >).  I can learn some new things from that.  My problem is if I set the height of `spinner`, the children don't look good anymore.  I edited my question to explain better how/why I need the height to be dynamically settable.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein - they seem to upscale fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/37za8/10/ (play around with the height). All the `>` means is the `a` is a direct child of `.ui-spinner`

Comment: @Pete That's very close.  I guess most of the "magic" came from setting `box-sizing`?  Not to be nitpicky, but I see the curve of the buttons on the top, but not on the bottom.  That makes me think that the button is larger than the container and getting trimmed.  Is there a way around that?

Comment: If you minus 2 it should work, the box-sizing property is meant to mean that the height should include padding and border, but for some reason it isn't taking account of the border for the inner elements (which is why you need to minus 2) http://jsfiddle.net/37za8/14/

Comment: @Pete Thanks.  That now looks exactly the way I wanted it to.  Could you post your comments as an answer?  I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a mixture of css and jquery you should be able to achieve what you want:

**css**

```
.ui-spinner,
.ui-spinner > a,
.ui-spinner-input {box-sizing:border-box;}
.ui-spinner > a {width:24px; text-align:center;}
.ui-spinner span.ui-icon {left:50%; margin-left:-8px;}
.ui-spinner-input {width:52px;}
```

**jquery**

```
var spinner = $(".ui-spinner"),
    children = spinner.children();

 spinner.height(48); //added for test purposes (if you change the height it should change the inner object heights)

children.height(spinner.height() - 2);  //minus 2 is because the box-sizing hasn't taken into account the borders for some reason
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/37za8/14/)

Answer (score 1):

you can calculate the height of the container and insert it in the height of the "a" element:

```
var _selector = ".ui-spinner"

var _inputvar = 25;

$(_selector).css("height", _inputvar);
$(_selector).css("line-height", "1");

console.log($(_selector).height());

$(_selector + " a").css("height", $(_selector).height());

$(_selector + " .ui-spinner-input").css("width", "52px");
$(_selector + " a").css("width", _inputvar);
$(_selector + " span").css({display:"inline-block",position:"static",marginTop:(_inputvar/10)+"px"});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/37za8/13/

Notice I removed the input height, depends on your set fonts you might need to put it back.
The margin top value can be optomized according to the expected range of values, I think in this case division by 10 works up to a certain point

By CSS you can do this (but it really comes down to how dynamic do you intend to go)

```
.ui-spinner {
    height: 25px;
}
.ui-spinner .ui-icon {
    left:4px;
}
.ui-spinner  .ui-state-default {
    padding: 12px;
}
ui-spinner-input {
    width: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/37za8/9/

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but I can't get it to work dynamically - http://jsfiddle.net/37za8/4/ .  If I set the height before outputting it, it's the right height in the console, but still doesn't look good.

Comment: so just to understand this better, is there some sort of code the sets the height dynamically? because from the looks of it, you really dont have to set the height at all

Comment: This is a simplified version.  It's intended to be a component that can be reused in multiple applications.  Some will want it to be 22 pixels, some will want it to be 28 pixels.  I need to be able to pass a height to it and have it draw properly.  (We can assume we won't pass a height smaller than the font, but that's about it.)

Comment: the height is easy to accommodate, you just need to fix line-height to 1, its vertical alignment that is tougher to break