# How to set up clickable boxes (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, onclick, click

I need to be able to set up kind of a navigatable menu. So like, there could be three boxes, each one with a number on it, and if you click on one of them it executes a certain code or takes one to another page. I feel dumb for not knowing how to do this, but I have success in everything but this, thanks so much!

Comment: Please show some code you have already. Perhaps a simplified version of the view/boxes, and one of the controllers you want to call when box 1 is clicked. Also please explain in more detail where you are stuck. The simplest form of what you are trying to do is an HTML link (the `<a>` element), could you say whether you have tried that,  or what it is about it that you don't get or cannot use for your purpose?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want, but simply, you'd need this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :pages

#app/views/elements/nav.html.erb
<% pages = %w(home about contact) %>
<% for page in pages do %>
    <%= link_to "Home", page_path(page) %>
<% end %>
```

You'll be able to style the boxes to [look like buttons using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121823/how-to-style-an-anchor-tag-to-look-like-a-button-with-the-same-height-as-the-but)